# Determining the first letter of the swift text field

Tags: swift, search, hashtag

I want to determine what the first letter is in a text field. I want to determine whether the first letter is @ or #. What should I do?

```
    func search() {
        
        searchBar.searchTextField.text?.first
    }
```

Comment: `hasPrefix()` might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare a variable with the characters you are checking for, and check if the first character of your `UITextField` is in that array:

```
let checkedCharacters = ["@", "#"]
if let firstCharacter = searchBar.searchTextField.text?.first {
    let containsCharacter = checkedCharacters.contains(firstCharacter)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make an optional string capable of checking for a prefix from a number of strings:

```
extension Optional where Wrapped: StringProtocol {
    func hasPrefix(_ ss: [String]) -> Bool {
        guard let s = self else { return false }
        return ss.first(where: s.hasPrefix) != nil
    }
}

searchBar.searchTextField.text.hasPrefix(["@", "#"])
```